# Could not stat the resume device file

Tags: power-management

I've copied one disk content to another disk and now when system boots I get this:

```
resume: libgcrypt version: 1.5.0
resume: Could not stat the resume device file '/dev/sda6' please type in full path name to try again or press ENTER to boot the system
```

The problem is now i don't have /dev/sda6. I removed this row from `fstab`, restarted system but I still get this message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to `fstab`, you also need to remove the disk from the boot process.

There are two things to check:

- uswsusp.conf - if there's any line like `resume /dev/sda7` there, comment it out.
- initramfs - update it with `update-initramfs -u -k all`

Comment: Jenny thanks for this awesome answer.  A lot of fixes for this same problem just list `update-initramfs -u` as the solution.  However your command fixed my problem when I realized that `-k all` updates all images for versions of kernels known to initramfs.  Thanks :)

Comment: @portforwardpodcast I'm glad it helped!

Comment: perfect! what worked here was to comment a line at uswsusp.conf pointing to a valid LVM swap (there seems to have some incompatibility between them), and well... I am on a desktop anyway.. thx!