# how to config lvmetad to skip directly to what matters?

Tags: boot, lvm

(it turned out to probably be an incompatibility with uswsusp.conf/hybernation and the referenced LVM swap by it, and that I am on a desktop not notebook)
(should I keep this question to help others in some way? the answer is in the comments too and from https://askubuntu.com/a/411589/46437)

`lvmetad is not active yet; using direct activation during sysinit`

kernel 4.4.0-83-generic 64bits
Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

when upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04, huge boot time > 5min, how to config lvmetad to skip directly to what matters?

all related questions have no answers that would work here, so I thought on trying to asking differently.

so, what I can configure at lvmetad to let it skip/ignore/jump directly to what matters instead of wating 5minutes for a simple boot? it seems to be some timeout thing, I read it could be a bug (if so we have no choice then)

some more info here:

so, the systemd-analyze leaves us clueless (well, the network manager 21s is extremely bad, but much less bad than the 5min)

```
systemd-analyze blame
     21.520s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      4.723s lvm2-activation-early.service
      3.063s systemd-udev-settle.service
      1.712s dev-mapper-LvmGroupRoot\x2droot.device
      1.556s hddtemp.service
...
```

its `plot` option is not better, if you try to visualize yours, make it sure to use `gwenview` (quite fast) (not imagemagick `display`, huge memory usage)

so, looking at dmesg I found this, making it clear it is a lvm problem.

```
[Sáb Jul  1 20:27:41 2017] floppy0: no floppy controllers found
[Sáb Jul  1 20:33:01 2017] EXT4-fs (dm-2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[Sáb Jul  1 20:33:01 2017] systemd[1]: systemd 229 running in system mode.
```

so I want to focus on tweaking lvmetad, any tips?

I had a hint that using an older kernel version would "solve" this problem , but of couse would not contain the newer kernel advantages..

I wont mess my gfx using `nomodeset`.

[the](https://askubuntu.com/a/886865/46437) lvm.conf use_lvmetad=0 makes no difference here.

I am still researching, will update as soon I have more info. It seems to require some expert about lvmetad :)

Comment: I believe that the lvmetad message is normal. What's wrong is your 5 minute boot times. Exactly what do you see on your screen when it seems to be taking so long? Edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab`. Ping me in a comment starting with `@heynnema` and I'll take a look.

Comment: @heynnema you are right, nothing to do with lvmetad, I had `/etc/uswsusp.conf` with `resume device = /dev/disk/by-uuid/76c1fa3...` that points to a LVM swap (I commented that line), and I am on a desktop machine (I was trying to resume at 14.04 but did not work). All other things related to `blkid`, `fstab`, `mount` where matching, there was no missing UUID.

Comment: I dont know if this question could be useful to others, I think it should be changed to really be about long boot time only, and the answer is about the problematic swap being tried to be used to resume on a desktop. any tips?

Comment: I don't recognize /etc/uswsusp,conf. What is that? You should check `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`. So, are your boot times OK now?

Comment: @heynnema wow, the RESUME is there too at initramfs! but.. after I changed the uswsusp.conf file my boot time is working great now, show I change that initramfs resume file too in some way? just to prevent some future surprise?

Comment: Yes, change it there also. Then do a `sudo update-initramfs -u`. You never said where uswsusp.conf came from and what it does.

Comment: @heynnema uswsusp is for hybernation. the update initramfs didnt change its resume file! I wonder if I can delete (bkp 1st) it, but I will try a boot see if it is still all ok (havent deleted it yet, may not either).

Comment: No, you edit the `resume` and update it with the proper UUID of the swap partition (taken from `sudo blkid` if you need to), then you do the `update-initramfs -u`